# Error: cannot find symbol of Parser

Tags: java, class, parsing, object, compiler-errors

So I have a class parser that goes something like this

```
public class Parser implements Serializable {

     //parse Programfile with name=filename
     public Program parseProgramFile(String filename){
         /*method defined*/
         return Program
     }
```

And on my main I am calling the parser to pass its return through another class constructor like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Manager manager = new Manager();
      String datafile = System.getProperty("import");
      if (datafile != null) {
        try {
    //Import file into Manager through Parser instance
    manager(parseProgramFile(datafile));
```

And this is where I keep getting it wrong

```
error: cannot find symbol
manager(parseProgramFile(datafile));
        ^
```

I'm really not sure of what I am doing wrong here. Is it the instantiation of parser gone wrong? I am currently creating a parser object in the manager constructor.

Comment: 'manager(parseProgramFile(datafile));' what this mean? we cant invoke **constructor method**  directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Java, static methods (like `main()`) can directly access/invoke other static members where as to access non-static methods from static methods, you need an object of the class (which holds the non-static methods).**

So, you need to create the object of the class `Parser` and invoke the method `parseProgramFile` (Option 1) or you can change `parseProgramFile` method to `static` (Option 2).

**Option(1): Create object for `Parser` and call from `main()`**

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
parser.parseProgramFile(parser.datafile);
```

**Option(2): Make `parseProgramFile` method as `static`**

```
public static Program parseProgramFile(String filename){
         /*method defined*/
         return Program
     }
```

and then in your `main()` you can invoke it as directly `manager(parseProgramFile(datafile));`

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more on static.

Comment: Did you mean `manager(parser.parseProgramFile(datafile));` in option 1?

Comment: @javaguy  the **manager** of **OP** is an object then 'manager(parser.parseProgramFile(datafile))' is legal??

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand what you mean completely. And I assume that the `Parser Object` is a `parameter` of your `Manager Constructor`

---

then an alternative solution is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Manager manager = null;
   String datafile = System.getProperty("import");
   if (datafile != null) {
     try {
         manager = new Manager(new Parser().parseProgramFile(datafile));
     ...
```